# SAP JCo program to get alerts using "SDF_CCMS_CON_GET_RZ20_ALERTS" rfc?

Tags: java

I have connected to the sap system and got JCoFUnction "SDF_CCMS_CON_GET_RZ20_ALERTS". Now how and what are the input parameters and output parameters to get required result. show me the result.

{ 
JCoDestination destination = JCoDestinationManager.getDestination(ABAP_AS_POOLED);

JCoFunction function = destination.getRepository().getFunction("SDF_CCMS_CON_GET_RZ20_ALERTS");

System.out.println(function);

//Get importPrameterList and set value

function.getImportParameterList().setValue(" ", " ");  //what are the inputes?

function.execute(destination);

System.out.println(function.getExportParameterList().getString(" "));  //what are the outputes?
}

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include all of the information you've provided in the comments section?

Answer (score 0):

Parameters for the function module can be found online: http://www.se80.co.uk/sapfms/s/sdf_/sdf_ccms_con_get_rz20_alerts.htm

Or even better, use transaction SE37 in your own system.

Note that this function module isn't enabled for remote usage. You will not be able to execute it via JCo.